# Error handling in deserialisation in redis CacheManager in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jackson

I am trying to use cutom serialisation for redis CacheManager in spring boot instead of using default java serialisation. How do I do error handling here? If there is a serialisation/deserialisation error, I want to delete the key from redis or atleast add a log line. Please find my implementation of custom serialisation using jackson

```
@Bean
RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
    StringRedisSerializer stringSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder()
            .allowIfSubType("com.example")
            .allowIfSubType("java.sql.Timestamp")
            .allowIfSubType("org.hibernate.collection")
            .allowIfSubType("java.util.List")
            .allowIfSubType("java.util.ArrayList")
            .build();
    mapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv, ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    RedisSerializer jacksonSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer(mapper);
    return new RedisCacheManager(
            RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(factory),
            RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
                    .serializeKeysWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(stringSerializer))
                    .serializeValuesWith(RedisSerializationContext.SerializationPair.fromSerializer(jacksonSerializer))

    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the solution that worked for me

**CustomCacheManagerErrorHandler**

```
@Slf4j
public class CustomCacheManagerErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        log.error("CacheGetError, cache_name={}, key={}", cache.getName(), key, exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        log.error("CachePutError, cache_name={}, key={}", cache.getName(), key, exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        log.error("CacheEvictError, cache_name={}, key={}", cache.getName(), key, exception);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        log.error("CacheClearError cache_name={}, key={}", cache.getName(), exception);
    }
}
```

**CacheConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport  {
    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler(){
        return new CustomCacheManagerErrorHandler();
    }
}
```